# > Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug FAILED Why am i getting this error

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am making an app in which whenever I connect the app to firebase and the Gradle build starts I get this error > Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug FAILED pls tell me why is it coming. I am been searching for this for hours but still cannot resolve this error pls help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDLt7.png)

Comment: You named something 300 that should start with a letter or _

Answer (score 0):

Tap first line please and upload screen again[image]